# pip install letencrypt, how do I know which packages are needed?

Tags: python, docker, package, apk

I'm reading this dockerfile for letsencrypt on Alpine:

https://github.com/CognitiveScale/lets-alpine/blob/master/Dockerfile

As I know, if I instlalled just `pip` with `apk`, or even `apk-get` on ubuntu, shouldn't the package manager also download any other needed libraries for `pip` to work? Why does this list of libs must be typed in the dockerfile?

```
RUN apk add --update  \
  python python-dev py-pip \
  gcc musl-dev linux-headers \
  augeas-dev openssl-dev libffi-dev ca-certificates dialog \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

I'm asking this because, what if I want to create images based on alpine, how am I going to know all the needed libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These Alpine packages are not needed for `pip` itself, presumably they are needed to build the Python modules that you will install with `pip` later.

You need to read module descriptions to determine their dependencies. Alternatively, you can follow the "trial and error" route and add the required Alpine packages when some Python modules fail to build.

Comment: but shouldn't pip take care of the dependencies needed to build the modules?

Comment: Python dependencies -- yes, OS dependencies -- no. Well, should or should not is an opinion; regardless, it _can not_ install OS packages.